# Autodelete generated files after shell script exits or crashes

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a pretty long bash process that generate a few temporary files, some of them, with generated and almost random names.

I will like to avoid to manually delete them after a process failure.
Is there a temporary directory, for example attached to the PID, that will be 'autodeleted' once the PID ends? If not, will be a nice addition.

One way will be to create `mkdir /tmp/$$` and use this directory as the global temp, however, will stay on `/tmp` after the abnormal end of the process.

I was expecting to use `trap "rm -rf /tmp/$$" EXIT` but doesn't work either and using trap... RETURN; is way too broad.

I'm looking for something generic, available for every shell or other user programs.

Is there an ephemeral directory YES or NO?

Comment: What type of "process failure" are you trying to catch?

Comment: What do you mean by "trap... doesn't work"?

Comment: failure: when running under cron/systemctl exit trap not always called. I'm not trying to catch anything.
'trap' doesn't work for this purpose.
However, this are not my questions: Is there an ephemeral directory YES or NO?

Comment: @fcm No there isn't, so it would be nice, don't you think, to try to sort out why your `EXIT` trap does not seem to work and how to do it correctly? When the script is run from `cron` or `systemctl`, is it the `bash` shell that is running it, or is it `/bin/sh`? If `/bin/sh` is the `dash` shell, then this may matter as they treat the `EXIT` traps differently.

Comment: Good point `Kusalanda`.  The `ExecStart=` line in `*.service` files does not use a shell and has limited support for syntax.  Some environment variables are set for you, but things like `&&` will not work.  You can call a bash script or use `/bin/bash -c "..."` from `ExecStart=` if you need bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How I'd do this is:

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
function cleanup {
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
}

trap cleanup EXIT
trap cleanup SIGINT
```

I tried a few use cases where this worked well:

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
function cleanup {
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
}

trap cleanup EXIT
trap cleanup SIGINT

echo "$tempdir"
sleep infinity
```

If I find the `PID` and `kill` (`SIGTERM`) it, the `$tempdir` is cleaned up
If I use CTRL+C (SIGINT), the `$tempdir` is cleaned up.

Here's another example:

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
function cleanup {
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
}

trap cleanup EXIT
trap cleanup SIGINT

echo "$tempdir"
set -e
/bin/false
```

This will simulate your "process failure".  When `false` returns, `set -e` will end this script.  The traps are still called and the directory is still deleted at the end.

If you have other conditions you need to catch, we can add more signals.  Do you have another use case that doesn't work?

The only thing you can't trap is `SIGKILL`.

Comment: This is a viable method, however it will require to add code to every batch using temp files. If we check our /tmp (or equivalent) directory is always dirty... and to reboot to clean it not a good option :)

Comment: So, you want to delete generated files, but you don't want to add any code do to it?  FYI as long as your generated files are all in `$tempdir/`, this boilerplate code will clean it so you DON'T have to reboot.

Comment: You are right: no additional code. The use of ephemeral files (or directories) allows you to use short lived files, for example on memory. For example '/run/$$' or similar. Another option: a hook.